# Link Dependency Property Data Context to DataGrid ItemSource

Tags: c#, arrays, arguments, default

Is it possible to have an optional 2-value array as argument?

I would like to pass `min` and `max` decimal values, respectively initialized to `-1000` and `1000` or anything else. I prefer to have neither multiple "similar" arguments, nor to create a such basic class.

Perhaps something like:

```
public void test(decimal[2] bounds = {-1000, 1000 } {} // I don't think I can specify a size before initialization

public void test(decimal[] bounds = new decimal[2]{ -1000, 1000 }) {}
```

Thanks for any insight :-)

**EDIT**

I think having a `Bounds` class is not a bad idea after all.. but is it possible to pass a default instance with the right `Min` and `Max` property?

```
    public class Bounds
    {
        decimal Min { get; } = -1000;
        decimal Max { get; } = 1000;

        public Bounds(decimal min, decimal max)
        {
            Min = min;
            Max = max;
        }
    }
```

PS Sorry, I haven't really done my own search-homerwork..

Comment: array cannot be compile time const ... so, well, no .. you cannot ... you can make it default null ... and check inside method if null was passed and replace with some static reaonly default value

Comment: moreover you cannot declare size of array in method definition ... why don't just use 2 parameters? `public void test(decimal min = -1000, decimal max = 1000) { ...  }`

Comment: Thanks! OK, it seems it is defintely a pain using array.. I prefer to gather the variable in order to extend them more easily if required. I edited my question with the `Bounds` class, but need to investigate it a bit myself.